# Accessing this in other scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I have problem with accesing this scope, how could i apply the this scope in neseted.

The problem is that I have no access to THIS in success method.

```
var Module = {
    els: {
        body: $('body')
    },

    success: function(result) {
        // Body is now undefined, no access to this
        console.log(result, this.els.body);
        // Access only via Module, this should be end result

        Module.els.body.html(result)
    },

    init: function() {
        $.get('/echo/jsonp', this.success);
    }

};

Module.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P6X8L/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using jQuery, you can use [`$.proxy(function, context`)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
$.get('/echo/jsonp', $.proxy(this.success, this);
```

without jQuery, you can use a closure

```
var myContext = this;
$.get('/echo/jsonp', function(X) { myContext.success(X); );
```

or

```
var myContext = this;
$.get('/echo/jsonp', function() { myContext.success.apply(myContext, arguments); );
```

Comment: Yes, i already forgot that in jQuery, Ill accept this as answer but are there any solutions beside using library ?

Comment: @jurka You could also use `Function.prototype.bind`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @Ian, brain was not working, forgot about that. Note: if you use bind and need to support IE8, you need to use the polyfill.